# Why isn't my arrow rotating downwards in css ( The span in there)

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HZ Digital Agency</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
        <header>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="container">
                    <img src="imgs/Logo.png" alt="" class="img">

                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html"></a>Home</li>
                        <li><a href="whowehelp.html"></a>Who We Help</li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="services.html"></a>Services
                            <span class="downArrow">&#62;</span>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="technology.html"></a>Technology</li>
                        <li><a href="company.html"></a>Company</li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </nav>

                <div class="cta"></div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Contact Us</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </header>






    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Above is the HTML , below is the CSS , I used transform : rotate(90deg); but it was not rotating. Any idea what is going on?

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@100;300;700&family=Poppins:wght@100;200;500;700&display=swap");

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: beige;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img {
  width: 110px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20;
  padding-right: 40px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.cta a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn-primary {
  margin-top: 2.1rem;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 8rem;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ee5f22;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 7%;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  border: none;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.downArrow {
  color: #ee5f22;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Is the problem that I am using a span ? or am I using the rotate in a wrong way ? I even changed rotation but it did not rotate in anyway . Thank you ! It is so weird because according to my knowledge it should work great with a span .

Comment: transform rules cannot be applied to inline elements, you need to reset display to any value, or make it float or use position:absolute or fixed so it has a size. Note that writing-mode is avalaible instead transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the display to `inline-block`.

```css
.downArrow {
  color: #ee5f22;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Inline elements are not transformable. According to the [specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-1/#transformable-element):

> A transformable element is an element in one of these categories:
>
> - all elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model except for non-replaced inline boxes, table-column boxes, and table-column-group boxes [CSS2],
> - all SVG paint server elements, the clipPath element and SVG renderable elements with the exception of any descendant element of text content elements [SVG2].

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@100;300;700&family=Poppins:wght@100;200;500;700&display=swap");

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: beige;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img {
  width: 110px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20;
  padding-right: 40px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.cta a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn-primary {
  margin-top: 2.1rem;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 8rem;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ee5f22;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 7%;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  border: none;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.downArrow {
  color: #ee5f22;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HZ Digital Agency</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
        <header>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="container">
                    <img src="imgs/Logo.png" alt="" class="img">

                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html"></a>Home</li>
                        <li><a href="whowehelp.html"></a>Who We Help</li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="services.html"></a>Services
                            <span class="downArrow">&#62;</span>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="technology.html"></a>Technology</li>
                        <li><a href="company.html"></a>Company</li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </nav>

                <div class="cta"></div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Contact Us</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>






    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `position: absolute;` to `.downArrow`

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@100;300;700&family=Poppins:wght@100;200;500;700&display=swap");

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: beige;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img {
  width: 110px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20;
  padding-right: 40px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.cta a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn-primary {
  margin-top: 2.1rem;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 8rem;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ee5f22;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 7%;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  border: none;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.downArrow {
  position: absolute;
  color: #ee5f22;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HZ Digital Agency</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
        <header>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="container">
                    <img src="imgs/Logo.png" alt="" class="img">

                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html"></a>Home</li>
                        <li><a href="whowehelp.html"></a>Who We Help</li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="services.html"></a>Services
                            <span class="downArrow">&#62;</span>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="technology.html"></a>Technology</li>
                        <li><a href="company.html"></a>Company</li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </nav>

                <div class="cta"></div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Contact Us</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </header>






    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add to span `display: inline-block;` css property:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@100;300;700&family=Poppins:wght@100;200;500;700&display=swap");

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: beige;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.img {
  width: 110px;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20;
  padding-right: 40px;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.cta a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn-primary {
  margin-top: 2.1rem;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 8rem;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #ee5f22;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 7%;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  border: none;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.downArrow {
display:inline-block;
  color: #ee5f22;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HZ Digital Agency</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
        <header>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="container">
                  <img src="imgs/Logo.png" alt="" class="img">

                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html"></a>Home</li>
                        <li><a href="whowehelp.html"></a>Who We Help</li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="services.html"></a>Services
                            <span class="downArrow">&#62;</span>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="technology.html"></a>Technology</li>
                        <li><a href="company.html"></a>Company</li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </nav>

                <div class="cta"></div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Contact Us</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </header>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`rotate()` doesn't work on inline elements, ie `<span>`.  Throwing a `display:inline-block` in there fixes it.

```css
span {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.ib {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  This is <span>inline</span>
</p>
<p>
  This is <span class="ib">inline-block</span>
</p>
```